# I can't get the resolution of 1334x750 whether through handbrake or ffmpeg

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, video-processing

With Handbrake, I could only get 1333x750. I tried to follow the advice given on [ffmpeg resizing video puts it at wrong resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228521/ffmpeg-resizing-video-puts-it-at-wrong-resolution/29249573#29249573) to force the aspect ratio to 1.79.

Apple however, is not accepting the file - some issues with the bitrate and stuff. Any other advice?

Answer (score 4):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906176/how-do-i-upscale-an-ios-app-preview-video-to-1080-x-1920/29906477#29906477) from @Benjamin Thiel

I added just for documentation.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=1080:1920,setsar=1:1 output.mp4 did the trick!

Turns out that ffmpeg tries to be smart about aspect ratio, so that the actual size is 1079x1920 with an aspect ratio of 2000:2001.

setsar=1:1 forces an aspect ratio of 1:1 and hence, the right resolution
-crf 12 as desired quality roughly results in the same file size as the original file created by iMovie, so it should be a safe bet bit rate-wise

Comment: This worked perfectly to resize an mp4 from 720 to 1334x750.